# why the program exits after i press Ok

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qfilesystemwatcher

I have written a program that watches over a directory and alerts when a file is added by a user, the file has specific format as user-name.files it works fine but when I press ok of the alert received of new file being added, the program exits, I want it it to stay running.

The below code I have written will run as child process of another PYQT application within that application. So in that I won't be executing main() but will just instantiate SendMyFiles object.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import sys
import os

class SendMyfiles(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SendMyfiles, self).__init__()
        self._lookInPath = "/Users/krystosan"
        self.filesList = os.listdir(self._lookInPath)
        print self.filesList
        self.watchMyfilesBin()

    def watchMyfilesBin(self):
        self.fileSysWatcher = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher()
        self.fileSysWatcher.addPath(self._lookInPath)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.fileSysWatcher,QtCore.SIGNAL("directoryChanged(QString)"), self,       
            QtCore.SLOT("slotDirChanged(QString)")) 
        # get list of files as files
        self.newFilesList = os.listdir(self._lookInPath)


    def _connections(self):
        pass

    def recievedfilesFromUser(self):
        newUsrFile =  list(set(os.listdir(self._lookInPath))^set(self.filesList))[0]
        userRecvdFrom = newUsrFile.split(".")[0]
        self.filesList.append(newUsrFile)
        return userRecvdFrom

    @pyqtSlot("QString")   
    def slotDirChanged(self, userfiles):
        userName = self.recievedfilesFromUser()
        retVal = QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Hello %s" % os.getenv('USER'), "Recieved files from %s." % userName)


def main():
    app     = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    fileSysWatcher  = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher() 
    window    = SendMyfiles()  
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I cannot reproduce this one (OpenSUSE 12.3 x64, PyQt 4.9.6).

I took your code and added a line `window.show()` to `main()` (despite your comment saying that you were "doing `window.show()`"). I also replaced the line

```
    userRecvdFrom = newUsrFile(".")[0]
```

with

```
    userRecvdFrom = newUsrFile.split(".")[0]
```

The former gives a runtime error because `newUsrFile` is a string and you can't call it.  I also changed the directory being watched as I don't have a directory with that name on my machine.

After doing this, I could reliably create files in the folder being watched and have the program pop up alert boxes.  After each alert was dismissed the program stayed running.

So I can only speculate at what the problem might be.  You say you are instantiating `SendMyfiles`, in code that you have chosen not to share with us, but how long does this object stay in existence for?  Do you keep a reference to this object, or is it only stored in a local variable and hence gets garbage collected at the end of a method?  If you have a PyQt window object, and all references to it are lost, Python will garbage-collect it, which will cause the underlying Qt C++ object to be deleted and the window closed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can find yopur answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772624/pyqt-dialog-how-to-make-it-quit-after-pressing-a-button), on a sidenote
I guess you mean the terminal that Windows opens for you when you run a python file is closed too fast. You can add `raw_input('Press Enter to exit')` right before your program would exit. It tells Python to wait for input before exiting, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open) also.

Comment: no Shivanshu, I didn't meant that. I am not on windows and moreover if you look at my code carefully I am to doing `window.show()`, what I meant is if something changes in the directory, then the prompt should come as it is coming but pressing ok should not quiet the running instance.

Comment: @san: "if you look at my code carefully I am doing `window.show()`"?  If you bother to look at your own code carefully, you can see that you quite clearly are not.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't provide you a very satisfactory answer, but hopefully this will help.

Firstly, the code example you have provided does not call `show()` on the `QMainWindow`.

It then appears that creating a `QMessageBox` when no main window is shown causes the Qt event loop (started by `app.exec_()`) to stop once the `QMessageBox` is closed. So modifying your code as follows will cause you application to behave as you expect:

```
window    = SendMyfiles()  
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

However, what I can't explain is why the event loop started by `app.exec_()` would end when the event loop for the QMessageBox ends. If anyone has insight, I'd love to hear why this happens!